# Viewing PDF in Android / Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, offline-caching, html5-appcache

I have a website caching pdfs offline with a .manifest-file.
On the desktop version of Chrome the PDF can be viewed offline inside Chrome. But on the Android Chrome nothing happens when I'm trying to open the cached PDF. No error message, just nothing.

I'm guessing the android default pdf-reader can't find the cached pdf? 
Anyone who knows how I can view the PDF in Android Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any Chrome hacks/custom settings available to view PDFs inside Andriod/Chrome? Just like the Desktop version.

Answer (score 3):

That's correct, browsers differ in terms of their built-in PDF support. One method you could explore is using [Mozilla's pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), which is a pdf reader built entirely in javascript that works just about everywhere. Make another web page that calls pdf.js and loads the PDF, and make sure all of that is in your cache manifest and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll have a look at it.